# how to solve turning off Location

Tags: java, android, location

I have following script to get Location using GoogleAPI. Working on My App is based on Location. When This Activity was opened, thanks to using GoogleAPI is got Location Known as Latitude and Longitude.

When MainActivity is opened, if Location turns on within Device Settings.(Android smart Phone).Location Knowledge is obtained as a successfully way and in MainActivity doesn't happen any Problems. Conversely, when Location Turns off on 
my android device, while the Activity is started, I have error and App close with a message that called  "Unfortunately The App has stopped".

How can I solve this problem? while The Activity is opening How to Control whether Location turns on or off.

thanks in advance for the whole help.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
    , LocationListener , DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
public static final String KEY_LOC_ADD_URL = "http://xxxxxxxx/android_api/insertlocation.php";
public static final String KEY_LATITUDE = "enlem";
public static final String KEY_LONGITUDE = "boylam";
public static final String KEY_ID="id";

private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
private LocationRequest locationRequest;
private Location mevcutKonum;

private String[] seconds={"1","3","5","7","10"};
private String sonGuncellemeZamani;
private String employee_id;
private Long requestTime;

private TextView enlemTextView;
private TextView boylamTextView;
private TextView sonGuncellemeTextView;
private TextView employee_name;



private AlertDialog dialogSelectInternal;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    enlemTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.enlem);
    boylamTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.boylam);
    sonGuncellemeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.guncellemezamani);
    sonGuncellemeZamani = "";
    employee_name= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userName);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    employee_name.setText("Welcome User " +      intent.getStringExtra(Login_Activity.KEY_USERNAME));
    employee_id=intent.getStringExtra(Login_Activity.KEY_ID);


    buildGoogleApiClient();
    selectRequestTimeDialog();
    createLocationRequest();

}





protected void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}

protected void createLocationRequest() {
    locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setInterval(3000)
            .setFastestInterval(1000)
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}

protected void startLocationUpdates() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
}

protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, this);
}








private void updateUI() {


    if (mevcutKonum != null) {
        enlemTextView.setText(String.valueOf(mevcutKonum.getLatitude()));
        boylamTextView.setText(String.valueOf(mevcutKonum.getLongitude()));
        sonGuncellemeTextView.setText(sonGuncellemeZamani);
    }
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    googleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
       stopLocationUpdates();
    }

    googleApiClient.disconnect();

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}




@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
   if (mevcutKonum == null) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return;
        }
        mevcutKonum = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
        sonGuncellemeZamani = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());

        try {
            addLocationToUser(String.valueOf(mevcutKonum.getLatitude()),String.valueOf(mevcutKonum.getLongitude()),employee_id);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        updateUI();


    }

    startLocationUpdates();

}



@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mevcutKonum = location;
    sonGuncellemeZamani = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
    updateUI();


}


private void addLocationToUser(final String latitude, final String longitude,final String id) throws JSONException {

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, KEY_LOC_ADD_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put(KEY_LATITUDE,latitude);
                params.put(KEY_LONGITUDE, longitude);
                params.put(KEY_ID,id);

                return params;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }


private void selectRequestTimeDialog(){

    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Konumunuzu Güncellemek istediğiniz zaman aralığını seçiniz");
    builder.setItems(seconds,this);
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
    dialogSelectInternal=builder.create();
    dialogSelectInternal.show();
}


@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


}
```

}

**Above Code has worked when location only turns on**

Answer (score 0):

In your `onCreate()` , First check if your GPS is enabled in your device, if yes create location update, else go to **Location Settings**.

```
if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            createLocationRequest();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enable your gps first.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent, 1);
        }
```

On GPS -> HIGH ACCURACY selection:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == 1) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1:
                createLocationRequest();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for help, but I didn't understand. Do I have to use each two methods which yours above and below code? @tahsinRupam

Comment: First code snippet checks if gps is on, if yes then get location or go to location settings of your device. Second code, executes if HIGH ACCURACY is selected then get location. Hopefully this will clear things.

Comment: Thanks so much your interested. I will try

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't working. I need to other solutions.